# react-i18next how to style

Tags: internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

How would I style the emailString variable?
I want to make it bold OR use a className?

```
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
const { t } = useTranslation("");
const emailAddress = "email@email.com"

            <div>
                {t("logoutCopy", { emailAddress: emailAddress })}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using Trans.

```
import { Trans, useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
const { t } = useTranslation("foo");

<Trans t={t} i18nKey="logoutCopy" >
blah blah <span className={css.bold}>{{ emailAddress }}</span>. blah blah
</Trans>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this

```
   <div>
    <span style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>
     {t("logoutCopy", { emailAddress: emailAddress })}
    </span/>
   </div>
```

or

```
  <div>
   <span className="your_classname">
    {t("logoutCopy", { emailAddress: emailAddress })}
   </span/>
  </div>
```

Comment: This does the whole translation. I only want the variable emailAddress